# Why it doesn't work? -- jQuery Plug In "Nested" --

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, nested

jQuery Plug In, "Nested" doesn't work.
"jqfloat" Plug In is working.
Do I need more divs!!?? I think jQuery is working but Nested has problem.
Help meeee!!!!

[jQuery Nested](http://suprb.com/apps/nested/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jqfloat.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.nested.js"></script>
        <script src="makeboxes.js"></script>


        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.boxes').jqFloat({
                width: 4,
                height: 4,
                speed : 1000
            });
        });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#boxxx').nested();
            });
        </script>
        <div id="boxxx">
            <div class="boxes 0">here</div>
            <div class="boxes 1">here</div>
            <div class="boxes 2">here</div>
            <div class="boxes 3">here</div>
            <div class="boxes 4">here</div>
            <div class="boxes 5">here</div>
            <div class="boxes 6">here</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forget nested selector in example.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#boxxx').nested({
                    selector: 'boxes'
                });
            });
        </script>

Comment: I tried this but it is also not working.

Comment: `$('#boxxx').nested({ selector: '.boxes' });` need "dot boxes"

Comment: I think there is another problem. Both plugins controlling elements `top` and `left` style property. I'm not shure that they can work together.
Try to run `nested` first and only after it  done (with some timeout) start float.

Comment: I checked the only one Plug-In can work. I tried that it doesn't work. I decided I'll continue my coding with one plug-in. Thank You, Arnial